# Perform variable chaining on ad hoc filters in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, template-variables

I have a dashboard in which I want to use an ad hoc filter and a query variable. I am able to chain two query variables so the output of one is determined by the previous one (Example: `label_values(cluster_name="$cluster_name")` ). But I would like to perform chaining with ad hoc filters. I want the query variable drop down to be determined by the ad hoc filter. I could not find any way to do it in the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/chained-variables/). Maybe there's a special symbol for ad hoc filter like $ for query variables? How do I go about doing this?

Also if that's not possible I would like to know how to chain within the ad hoc filter (chaining between variables in the AND operator of the ad hoc filter).

PS: My data source is a Prometheus server, if that helps.